# What function to use in Excel to count all numerical values of one variable on the basis of the values of another variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, r

I'd appreciate some help with working with the data set with Excel.

I have a big data table with 4 variables in columns and multiple cases in rows.

The Sector variable shows what type of sector the case belongs to, e.g. A01, A02....C01, etc. There also is a country variable describing data's origins and year describing when the data was collected.

M_EUR is a numerical variable describing how much money was spent; it also has a lot of NAs, indicating that there is no numerical data.

Here is a smaller version of the dataset:
[image: Here is a smaller version of the dataset.]

What I want to do is to calculate how many numerical values M_EUR variable has for each sector. So, in the case of the data set shown above, Excel would return to me that M_Eur has 8 numerical values for Sector A01.

It would be best if the code could be re-used quickly and easily for many sectors

I am aware that there is a similar topic on R at StackExchange, though I am incapable of determining which function I should use for I am still a rookie in the game. (Here's a link to the discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family).

Comment: Why you do not use PivotTable? rows = Sector, function = M_Eur, numbers count...

Comment: Power Query can also get your result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this formula in Excel:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,D:D,">=0")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Since you are handling huge data set therefore I would like to suggest two steps solution to fix the issue.*

**Step 1:**

- Summarizing the **Sector** Column, creating unique list of Sectors.
- It avoids to enter Sector's Value from Keyboard, saves time also.
- Array Formula in Cell `E39`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$39:$A$65, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$38:E38, $A$39:$A$65), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Finish Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

**Step 2:**

- Count the corresponding Numbers in Column `D`.
- Formula in Cell `F39`:

  ```
  =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$39:A$65=E39)*(D$39:D$65<>"NA"))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(--(A$39:A$65=E39)*(D$39:D$65<>"NA")))
  ```

[image]

**N.B.**

- I've used `IF` with `SUMPRODUCT` to replace `0` with `Blanks`.
- You may use this formula also to replace zero with balnks.

  ```
   =TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$39:A$65=E39)*(D$39:D$65<>"NA")),"0;-0;;@")
  ```
- If you are expecting regular updates in data set then better use **Dynamic Named Range** for **Sector** & **M-Eur** Columns.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*